# With Asterisk, how to make a call between 2 externals then hangup?

Tags: asterisk, transfer, forward

My problem is the following.

I want:

- to be called by A
- read a code from A (ex. *15334#*)
- retrieve the phone number of B from a database with the code readed from A
- call B
- once A is in communication with B, hangup after 3 seconds

For now, it works, **BUT when I hangup (after 3 seconds), communication between A and B is closed**.

A and B are external numbers.

**How to hangup server without closing communication between A & B?**

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Doing it way you did it called "bridged call". So when you close bridge,it hangup. You need transfer call. Unfortanly that require transfer support from provider side. For sure no one of providers will do this for you for zero cost.

Provider can organize that using other asterisk(at provider side) or special hardware pbx or other hardware/softswitch solution. If provider can do that feature for you, provider will inform you how to do. For example some provider allow do transfer using flash+dtmf command(on analog lines).